# How to calculate the difference of datetime field and now in Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.7

I have a `datetime` field in my database that contains the following information:

```
2015-08-04 18:59:01
```

I want to check the difference between that `datetime` field and now using `Cakephp framework` ?

Comment: mysql, presumably? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 2):

See [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$date = '2015-08-04 18:59:01';
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $now->diff($dateTime);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

See [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) for other formatting options.

You can also get diff in seconds:

```
$date = '2015-08-04 18:59:01';
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
$diff = time() - $dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: is there an other method using cakephp helpers ?

Comment: You can use `TimeHelper::timeAgoInWords` for formatted interval or `TimeHelper::toUnix` to get time in unix timestamp. See [TimeHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html) for more info and usage examples.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference between two dates:

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");

$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

Output:
+272 days

The date_diff() function returns the difference between two DateTime objects.